# Batch program - using variable as end in for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to create a simple batch program that will execute the same application X number of times based on a for loop.

Here is what I currently have:

```
@echo off
set "processCount=4"
FOR %%G in (0, 1, %processCount%) DO START "VSSampleToInvokeCOM.exe" "VSSampleToInvokeCOM.exe"
```

This nearly works but I only ever get 3 instances of the application. I've tried multiple iterations of this same for loop without any change in the results.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /L %%G in (0, 1, %processCount%) DO START "VSSampleToInvokeCOM.exe" "VSSampleToInvokeCOM.exe"
```

You need the `/L` switch to loop from start to end. Without it, `FOR` just sees a list of - **3** items...